# maven time build property in timestamp

Tags: maven

I'm using maven's property to get time of project build.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy--mm-dd hh-mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

And then i can get it on my jsp page like this

```
${initParam.buildTimeStamp}
```

But i'm wondering is there a way how to get time in timestamp format. For example if time of build is 2015-01-17 10-23-57 then in timestamp it should look like 1421490237

Comment: Check `buildnumber-maven-plugin` -  http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i'm wondering is there a way how to get time in timestamp format

Maven documentation states this:

> The format pattern has to comply with the rules given in the API
>   documentation for SimpleDateFormat.
>   https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

And the SimpleDateFormat API documentation does not mention any way to get the raw "milliseconds-since-epoch" format that you're looking for.

So, I think it's not possible with the built-in Maven build timestamp.
However, in your JSP, you could parse the date with SimpleDateFormat - that'll give you a Date object, and then you can extract this long value from it.